# How to monitor linux oracle log file into cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Could someone help me to terraform the Oralce log file in linux server to CloudWatch log group.

Comment: You need to install the CloudWatch agent and tell it where to look, e.g., point it to a log file.

Comment: there are different ways to achieve this. This article shows how to deal with the cloud watch agent: https://cloudlad.io/cloudwatch-agent-as-a-terraform-module This is how you create the cloudwatch log group; https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_log_group - those should be good starting points

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.